How to create a border for an image that's been resized with object-fit: scale-down
I have a JavaScript slideshow that displays images of various dimensions in a browser window. It uses object-fit: scale-down to resize the image to fit the container. I'd like to add a border to the image, but when I apply the style border: 2px solid black to the <img> element, it seems to surround what would be the image in its original, unscaled size.
Is there a way, either with CSS or with JavaScript, to apply the border to the resized image?
Update: I'd prefer a solution that allows me to use the border-family of style settings, even if it requires some JavaScript.


const duration = 2000; // time (msec) to display each slide
const sizes = [
  [4000, 500],
  [1000, 4000],
  [600, 400],
  [100, 200]
];
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let size_index = 0;

function show_slides(duration) {
  let this_duration = duration;
  const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
  if (size_index == sizes.length) {
    size_index = 0;
  }
  let w = sizes[size_index][0];
  let h = sizes[size_index][1];
  ++size_index;

  let my_randomizer = `https://placehold.co/${w}x${h}?text=${w}+x+${h}\npx`;
  fetch(my_randomizer)
    .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
    .then(my_blob => {
      let my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      sleep(this_duration)
        .then(() => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(my_parent.querySelector('img').src);
          my_parent.querySelector('img').src = my_url;
          show_slides(duration);
        });
    })
    .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  /* prevent body from displacing */
  margin: 0;
  /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* Now create left/right margins */
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* hints the contents to not overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  /* force the div to fill the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.picture-div-img {
  /* force the image to stay true to its proportions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* and force it to behave like needed */
  object-fit: scale-down;
  object-position: center;
  /* does not properly enclose image: */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Self-contained slideshow demo -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="show_slides(duration);">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Epsom</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <!-- This div will hold the <img> -->
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
        <!-- Placeholder <img> element for slides -->
        <img class="picture-div-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of inner-remaining-div -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of outer-div -->
</body>

</html>




You can use max-width and max-height and include calculated padding/margin. I added flex with column axis, justify content and align items to the parent div of image to center. Also added a calculation in CSS for the added margin.


const duration = 2000; // time (msec) to display each slide
const sizes = [
  [4000, 500],
  [1000, 4000],
  [600, 400],
  [100, 200]
];

const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let size_index = 0;

function show_slides(duration) {
  let this_duration = duration;
  const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
  if (size_index == sizes.length) {
    size_index = 0;
  }
  let w = sizes[size_index][0];
  let h = sizes[size_index][1];
  ++size_index;

  let my_randomizer = `https://placehold.co/${w}x${h}?text=${w}+x+${h}\npx`;
  fetch(my_randomizer)
    .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
    .then(my_blob => {
      let my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      sleep(this_duration)
        .then(() => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(my_parent.querySelector('img').src);
          my_parent.querySelector('img').src = my_url;
          show_slides(duration);
        });
    })
    .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /* prevent body from displacing */
  margin: 0;
  /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* Now create left/right margins */
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* hints the contents to not overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  /* force the div to fill the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* center child elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.picture-div-img {
  max-width: calc(100% - 1em); /* included 0.5em * 2 margin on parent */ 
  max-height: calc(100% - 2em); /* included 2em margin on parent, may need adjust this further */ 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Self-contained slideshow demo -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="show_slides(duration);">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Epsom</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <!-- This div will hold the <img> -->
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
        <!-- Placeholder <img> element for slides -->
        <img class="picture-div-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of inner-remaining-div -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of outer-div -->
</body>

</html>




(1) can you make it centered vertically as well? (2) is object-position: center still needed?

Also, I needed max-height: calc(100% - 1em) to avoid clipping the border at the bottom.

@Chap I added flex property to parent element to center.

It appears from testing on various MacOS and iOS browsers that object-center is unnecessary. Could you check that picture-div and picture-div-img styles properties are all necessary, and update your summary of your changes at the top of your answer?

I edited the answer, let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

This is fantastic. My only question is, what is the relationship between the border width (2px here) and the small constant you subtract from max-width and max-height? If I used a 10px border, what should I subtract from max-width and max-height?

If you use border-box as your box-sizing, it tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height, however if you use content-box the width of any border or padding will be added to the final rendered width. See the following MDN article on box-sizing

The CSS calc on width and height is to accommodate the margin on parent elements.

You can approximate it using a drop-shadow filter:


const duration = 2000; // time (msec) to display each slide
const sizes = [
  [4000, 500],
  [1000, 4000],
  [600, 400],
  [100, 200]
];
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let size_index = 0;

function show_slides(duration) {
  let this_duration = duration;
  const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
  if (size_index == sizes.length) {
    size_index = 0;
  }
  let w = sizes[size_index][0];
  let h = sizes[size_index][1];
  ++size_index;

  let my_randomizer = `https://placehold.co/${w}x${h}?text=${w}+x+${h}\npx`;
  fetch(my_randomizer)
    .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
    .then(my_blob => {
      let my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      sleep(this_duration)
        .then(() => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(my_parent.querySelector('img').src);
          my_parent.querySelector('img').src = my_url;
          show_slides(duration);
        });
    })
    .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.picture-div-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  object-position: center;
  border: 2px solid #0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px black) drop-shadow(0 0 1px black) drop-shadow(0 0 1px black);
}
<body onload="show_slides(duration);">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Epsom</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <!-- This div will hold the <img> -->
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
        <!-- Placeholder <img> element for slides -->
        <img class="picture-div-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of inner-remaining-div -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of outer-div -->
</body>




This works, as a good fallback. I amended OP to specify ability to use border-family stylings.
